# add-migration is combining all contexts schema/table

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.0

I've 2 `DbContext` in my project. `ApolloContext` & `MasterContext` and corresponding 2 different databases `Apollo` & `Master`.

When i try to run below `add-migration`, I can see `MasterContext` tables also in `20190925053849_InitalApollo.cs`. How can i create 2 separates model snapshots

```
add-migration InitalApollo -Context ApolloContext -OutputDir Migrations/Apollo
```

-

```
public partial class ApolloContext : DbContext
{
    public ApolloContext()
    { }
    public ApolloContext(DbContextOptions<ApolloContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Employer> Employer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Assembly assemblyWithConfigurations = GetType().Assembly; //get whatever assembly you want
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assemblyWithConfigurations);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

--

```
public class MasterContext : DbContext
{
    public MasterContext()
    { }

    public MasterContext(DbContextOptions<MasterContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        Assembly assemblyWithConfigurations = GetType().Assembly; //get whatever assembly you want
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assemblyWithConfigurations);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

-
**Workaround**: I've created 2 separates projects for each context and working fine.. is there a way to do in single project with more than one DbContext

Comment: Does/did ApolloContext inherit from MasterContext?

Comment: No. Both are separate.